# Hold focus on textbox that do something in the textchanged event

Tags: c#, wpf, focus

I have a problem:
I handled textchanged event of a textbox. When the event fires I do something in the UI (like add a row in a listbox) and the textbox lost the KeyboardFocus.
How can I hold the KeyboardFocus on that textbox?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Write the following

```
this.MyTextBox.Focus()
```

at the end of your handler.
or make your `UIElement.Focusable = false`. it should help.

Comment: The problem is that I want to set the KeyboardFocus and not only logical focus. KeyboardFocus is assigned to the Listbox and it seems to be locked. I tried `MyTextBox.Focus();` and `Keyboard.Focus(MyTextbox);` but don't work.

Comment: Try to use `MyTextBox.CaretIndex = MyTextBox.Text.Length - 1;`

Answer (score 0):

You can set the focus back on the textbox in the code-behind where you handle the event using textBoxName.Focus();

Focus can be set in the XAML using 
FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=textBoxName}"

but if the focus is lost when you add a new element then you may need to use code-behind to reset it.